# ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_rule' from 'werkzeug.routing'

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-restx

I got the following message after running my Flask project on another system.
The application ran all the time without problems:

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 214, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projekt\app\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_restx import Namespace, Api
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\api.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .swagger import Swagger
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\swagger.py", line 18, in <module>
    from werkzeug.routing import parse_rule
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_rule' from 'werkzeug.routing' (c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing\__i
nit__.py)
```

My requirements.txt

```
Flask~=2.1.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
flask-restx==0.5.1
qrcode~=7.3.1
PyPDF2==2.6.0
reportlab~=3.6.10
WTForms~=3.0.1
flask-bootstrap==3.3.7.1
flask-wtf==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The workaround I use for now is to pin werkzeug to 2.1.2 in `requirements.txt`. This should only be done until the other libraries are compatible with the latest version of Werkzeug, at which point the pin should be updated.

```
werkzeug==2.1.2
```

Answer (score 26):

**UPDATE:** This has now been fixed, you should be using version 1.0.3 or greater for `flask-restx`.

**ORIGINAL:** This is caused by `parse_rule()` being marked as `:internal:` on the latest release of `werkzeug` which impacts `flask-restx` (plus many others such as `flask-login`).

https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/issues/460 is open for `flask-restx`, https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/686 for `flask-login`.

As you've mentioned, pinning to an older version is the workaround for now (i.e. `werkzeug==2.1.2`).

Answer (score 10):

Copying here from the github issue for those who find this. If you are using with Flask and try to downgrade to Werkzeug 2.1.2 you will get an error because flask wants 2.2.x from Werkzeug. You will need to downgrade flask as well as follows:

```
Werkzeug <= 2.1.2   
flask == 2.1.2   
flask-restx >= 0.5.1
```

Answer (score 2):

This Issue is come from latest version of flask. Based on most suggestions Flask was downgraded  to `v2.1.2`. The latest version of Flask requires Werkzeug >=`2.2.0` but Flask `v2.1.2` requires Werkzeug >=`2.0`. Therefore Werkzeug was downgraded to `v2.1.2`.

if you're using `pip` just install following versions using terminal:

```
pip3 install Flask==2.1.2
pip3 install Werkzeug==2.1.2
```

Hope it will solve your issues!